# ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, parseexception

Why am I getting this exception?

Here is my format string:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

Here is the string I want to format:

```
2012-12-29T23:59:00-05:00
```

But I get the following exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-12-29T23:59:00-05:00"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at objectmodels.Checkout.setDueDate(Checkout.java:72)
    at threads.AccountNotifyThread.lookupAccountInfo(AccountNotifyThread.java:220)
    at threads.AccountNotifyThread.performNotificationsForUser(AccountNotifyThread.java:65)
    at threads.AccountNotifyThread.run(AccountNotifyThread.java:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It because `Z` expects `-0500` and not `-05:00` so the date should be `2012-12-29T23:59:00-0500`.

You'll have to get rid of that last `:`

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");

Try the z instead of Z.

Comment: For that the timezone will have to be `GMT-05:00`